# MySQL: Writing log entries from stored procedure

Tags: mysql, debugging, log

Is there a standard way to write log messages in MySQL stored procedures?

I can write [log messages to a designated log table](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/debugging-mysql-stored-procedures/218100564?pgno=2), but I prefer the standard log mechanism where each message is coupled with severity and sent to an external file.

Comment: Do you mean something like `RAISE NOTICE` in PostgreSQL?

Comment: If it's redirected to the log files, yes.

Comment: I believe the answer is 'not easily', but you should join the dark side and realize that storing date/time sensitive information (like logs) is a great use for databases.  Sure beats parsing date strings with perl.